# How can I disable the Draper decorator generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, draper

In my Rails 3.2 app's `application.rb` I have the following lines to disable scaffold generators I don't want:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # rest of the config...

    config.generators do |g|
      g.helper false
      g.stylesheets false
      g.javascripts false
    end
  end
end
```

The app is using the [Draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) and if I run `rails generate` then `decorator` is listed as one of the available generators. I assumed that adding `g.decorator false` to the above list would prevent `rails generate scaffold SomeModel` from generating the decorator files but they're still created. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please?

Comment: Is this really an issue for you? I haven't used scaffolding since I first started learning Rails. If you're disabling so much of the scaffolding functionality, why not just use the controller generator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735468/why-do-ror-professionals-not-use-scaffolding

Comment: I'm building a large app with a lot of models which already has all of it's HTML mocked up so I've customised the view generators (and added i18n support). It's worth it for the time that typing `rails g scaffold Thing title body:text option:boolean amount:integer other_thing:references` saves me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draper is configured to have decorators built by default for every controller.  You can change the default configuration with one additional line in your application.rb file...

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # rest of the config...

    config.generators do |g|
      g.helper false
      g.stylesheets false
      g.javascripts false
      g.decorator   false
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the interesting bit from Draper...

https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/master/lib/generators/controller_override.rb

Called from the Railtie...

https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/master/lib/draper/railtie.rb

Note that you can still generate decorators explicitly...

```
$ rails generate decorator foo
```