# Rails 4: Render a form to different pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I develop a website using Rails 4.
In this website there is a company form which should be located also in the job form.
I wonder what would be the best practice to render this form to a different page. 
The companies and the jobs are created via scaffold so every form has their route

Comment: please paste your model relationship and what you want to achieve

Comment: Don't use scaffolding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735468/why-do-ruby-on-rails-professionals-not-use-scaffolding

Answer (score 1):

Create a `partial` for the common form eg: `_common_form.html.erb`.
Then in your company and job views, you can use the same form by calling the render method.

`<%= render 'common_form'%>`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the form to the separate folder, **shared** for example. And then render the form from the company/job pages with params:

`<%= render :partial => 'shared/company', :locals => { :company => @company } %>`